# Python invalid literal sort program

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" error.
My specifications:

1. Your program must generate a random list of integers whose length and range of values will be specified at run time.
2. You must show the unsorted list.
3. You must show that the list contains the user specified number of entries.
4. You must write and demonstrate code to prove that all of the values in the list lie within the range specified by the user.
5. You must use your own implementation of insertion sort in order to create a list that contains all of the items in the original list in ascending order.
6. You must display the elements of the sorted list as the list is being built.
7. You must display the sorted list.

My code

```
import random

length = input("Input the length of the random list: ")
temp = input("Input the range of values for the random list (0-n)")

def gen_list(L, T):
    LIST = []
    ranlower = T[0:T.index('-')]
    ranhigher = T[T.index('-')+1:len(T)]
    for num in range(L):
        x = random.randint(int(ranlower),int(ranhigher))
        LIST.append(x)
    tempmax = ranlower
    tempmin = ranhigher
    for i in range (L):
        for t in range (L):
            if LIST[t] > tempmax:
                tempmax = LIST[t]
            if LIST[t] < tempmin:
                tempmin = LIST[t]
    print("Unsorted List: ", LIST)
    print("The largest value in the list was: ", tempmax, " with upper bound at ", ranhigher, ".")
    print("The smallest value in the list was: ", tempmin, " with lower bound at ", ranlower, ".")
    print("The random unsorted list has ", L, " items.")
    sort_numbers(LIST)

def sort_numbers(s):
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        # let's see what values i takes on
        print ("i = ", i)
        val = s[i]
        j = i - 1
        while (j >= 0) and (s[j] > val):
            s[j+1] = s[j]
            j = j - 1
            print (s)
        s[j+1] = val
    print(s)

gen_list(length, temp)
```

This is the full traceback:

```
Input the length of the random list: 10
Input the range of values for the random list (0-n)
10-15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/folders/8_/7j1ywj_93vz2626l_f082s9c0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/Program 1-437933490.889.py", line 42, in <module>
    gen_list(length, temp)
  File "/private/var/folders/8_/7j1ywj_93vz2626l_f082s9c0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/Program 1-437933490.889.py", line 13, in gen_list
    x = random.randint(int(ranlower),int(ranhigher))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Your stack trace has `x = random.randint(int(ranlower),int(ranhigher))`, but your code has `x = random.randint(int(ranlower),int(ranhigher)))`. They are different. Please post the actual code that caused your error.

Comment: The problem comes from the `temp` variable who should be a string and not an int, try to pass it to your program as a string it will work better.
Peace

Comment: @TheLegendWhoLived, I'm still not getting the error that you reported. I either get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'` in Python 2.7, or `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` in Python 3.4.

Comment: Try using raw_input() instead of input().
Currently your input() parses a wrong value of T.  

    length = raw_input("Input the length of the random list: ")
    temp = raw_input("Input the range of values for the random list (0-n)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error message, you're trying to call `int()` on an empty string (`''`).

Since the line that produces the error contains two calls to `int()`, it means that either `ranlower` or `ranhigher` is an empty string. Find out why (`print` statements are helpful there) and your problem will be solved.